# Update Javascript variable from PHP without page reload

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jCart as shopping cart, and from jCart it's possible to get the variable `$subtotal`.

However, when changing something in the shopping cart, the variable `$subtotal` doesn't change until a page reload.

Is it possible to use jQuery to update `$subtotal` on page click with `.click(function())` ?

Comment: Yes. You need to use an AJAX request to post the cart to your PHP page, and return the `$subtotal` variable.

Comment: You should post it as an answer Rory

Comment: How can a PHP variable even exist when there isn't any PHP code running?

Comment: Variable `$subtotal` is propably read from `$_SESSION` or some other kind of storage system (`jcart`).  In this case you can update it by using ajax requests, also you can update client vars by reading them from ajax reply.

Comment: There was some problems(?) with my answer so updated it (covers both client side and server side) and added simple JSFiddle doing `client side only` updates, here http://jsfiddle.net/QfS68/ and same with many _products_ http://jsfiddle.net/QfS68/1/

Answer (score 3):

*The question is flawed to begin with.*

PHP runs server side. When all PHP is done, it gets presented to the browser and all the variables are gone. Maybe you're echoing some of them, so they are "there" in literal format, **but there is no PHP variable anymore to update.**

You can update something, like a javascript variable that you have filled before trough PHP, or a HTML value that got set by PHP. This can be done by reload, or this can be done by using an AJAX post, then some PHP magic, then a return + assign, but you are NOT replacing/reloading any PHP variables.

It is REALLY important to understand that **there is no `$subtotal` anymore** whatsoever after you've send the page to the browser. Please look into server side versus client side!

Comment: You can update `server side` variables using `client requests`, and that is done by ajax requests if page should not be reloaded or maybe even updated. When asking for `file.php` that contains vars, they will get updated.

Comment: There is no server side variable anymore, so there is nothing to update. All you have is client side variables. After that file.php is loaded the variables ARE GONE. You can update their counterpart in your page (javascript, html), but there is NO server side variable anywhere after the loading is done.

Comment: Yes, but question was how to update server side variables without reloading page and ajax is just for that. You are right, there is no server side vars at client side but question is not how to use server side vars with client at this point but how to update them. For example if server side var needs to stored and updated using previous value then we can use `$_SESSION`. And does update always need to know previous values? I think that answer is no, you can update some values even if they are null, most propably then you insert some meaningful data.

Comment: Let me put this another way. You are looking at a page that was build by PHP. The mentioned `$subtotal` was used while building the page, but it is gone now. There _IS_ no `$subtotal`. Therefore you CAN NOT update it. There is no need to update it, as it is not there. Now you can update a `$_SESSION` var, obviously, but that is something else. You can also change something in your database, change something on your screen. All that is possible, but that has *nothing* to do with that `$subtotal`. You can not update something which is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a JSFiddle of an ajax post example here (without page reload): http://jsfiddle.net/5RjUt/1/

JQUERY

```
$("#button").click(function(){ // click function fired

var subtotal = $("#subtotal").val()
var dataString = 'subtotal=' + subtotal;

$.ajax({ // ajax post
    type: "POST",
    url: "YOUR_PHP_PAGE.php", // post data to this URL
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){ // this is where you can set a success callback
       $("#subtotal").val("You're new value");
    }
});
return false; // this tells the page not to refresh

)};​
```

Comment: Please refer to Nanne's answer above as I clearly misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

### It is a bit unclear what you are trying to do

But here is some suggestions.

---

### Use jQuery to update Client side only:

If you need to update some visible value on web page, let's say you just need to increment or decrement `subtotal` displayed on web page then you can do this with jQuery without any server side processing.

#### Client side processing (Javascript / jQuery):

```
var subtotal = 0;

// Add value to subtotal and update div displaying subtotal
function addToSubtotal( value ) {
    subtotal += value;
    $('#subtotal').html(subtotal);
}

// When DOM is loaded...
$(document).ready( function(){
    // Bind onclick event to every <a class="buyme">
    $('.product').on('click', 'a.buyme', null, function(e){
        // Buyme link clicked, add <span class="pricetag"> value to subtotal:
        addToSubtotal( parseInt( $(this).siblings('.pricetag').html() ));
    });
});
```

​

#### Client side processing (HTML):

```html
<div class="product">
    <a class="buyme" href="#">Add to subtotal</a><br/>
    <span class="pricetag">55</span>€
</div>
<br/>
<span id="subtotal">0</span>​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

### Or use jQuery.ajax() to update Server side:

You can use this to update JS variables too, especially needed if server checks and returns `subtotal`. In this case it is actually server that returns new subtotal value for you.

It seems that your PHP variable `$subtotal` is first read from some data storage system, it may look like it is always there it it is initially set for example when doing `$myStore = new onlineStore();`.

I assume that `$subtotal` is already available and contains some consistent integer value.

#### Code for AJAX update requests (server side and client side):

This will update `server side` PHP variables if properly used, and retrieve them for use with `client side` jQuery / Javascript.

However, this function will not do it out-of-box and should be only used as starting point for your complete implementation.

#### Client side processing (javascript/jquery):

```
function updateSubtotalAtServer( args ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'processing.php', // <= Request url
        // Add method=ajax, we use PHP to check that value
        data: $(args).serialize()+"&method=ajax",
        // processing.php returned some data:
        success: function(data){
            // Try decoding data as JSON encoded string:
            try { 
                dataobj = $.parseJSON(data);
            } catch (e) { 
                dataobj = null;
            }
            // Check if JSON return value decoded successfully:
            if (dataobj !== null) {
                // Successfully decoded JSON, log values to console.
                // ...update subtotal <span> to display it for user:
                $('#subtotal').html( dataobj.subtotal );
                console.log( dataobj );
            } else {
                // Result was not JSON string (server error).
            }
        }
    });
}

// Create new object to be used as array:
var arrayobject = new Object;
// Add this value at server side to $subtotal:
arrayobject.addtosubtotal = 55;
// Then send ajax request to server:
updateSubtotalAtServer( yourvariables or array object );
```

#### Server side processing (php):

```php
// Variable that needs updating:
/* $subtotal is already available, ..read above.. */ 

if (isset($_POST['method']) && $_POST['method'] == 'ajax') {
    // Update variables:
    $subtotal += (int)$_POST['addtosubtotal'];
    // Put all data together what is needed at client side:
    $ajaxreply = array( 'subtotal' => $subtotal, 'othervalue' => 'FooBar' );
    // Return it to browser:
    echo json_encode( $ajaxreply );
    // JSON reply will fail if there is any additional output after that.
    exit;
}
```

More reading / maybe helpful answers:
[Another answer about jQuery.ajax, focusing on REST, forms and data arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10235181/1338846)
[Another answer about jQuety.ajax, fetch data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197507/displaying-images-with-ajax/10198264#10198264)

Comment: And what is wrong with my answer, at least server side vars gets updated when requesting PHP file from server. At least with my server :)

Comment: Added simple JSFiddle doing `client side only` updates, here http://jsfiddle.net/QfS68/ and same with many _products_ http://jsfiddle.net/QfS68/1/